# How to print multiple input values from a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that will return a High Score with the associated Player Name and Game Played based on input

```
from collections import defaultdict
scores = {}
d = defaultdict(list)

while True:
    name = input("Please give me the name of the player [q to quit]:")
    if name == 'q':
        break
    else:
        score = input("Give me their score:")
        scores[name] = score
        game = input("Tell me the name of the game they got this score in:")
        d.setdefault(name, [score]).append(game)


highScore = max(scores.values())
    for k, v in scores.items():
    if v == highScore:
        print("High Scorer:", k,"High Score:", v)
```

What I get is: 
High Scorer: Sue, High Score: 125

What I am looking for is:
High Scorer: Sue, High Score: 125, Game Played: Rummy

Comment: What have you tried so far to print the `Game Played` part?

Comment: I tried: print("Game:", v.append) and what I got is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Todd/PycharmProjects/commandline/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    for k, v, v.append in scores.items():
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Comment: Why are you using append command to get a value from a dictionary? Also, your error is coming from somewhere else (line 20)

Comment: I assumed that because I added the value with .append that this might work...I am VERY new to Python and know no other programming languages.

Comment: Then please go through Python tutorials first since this is your first programming language. Also, learn [how to debug a program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and read documentation on how to use the functions